# UserControl InitializeComponents() method set the Content property, but does NOT trigger binding update

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

For example, there is a class **MyUserControlBase** derived from **UserControl** and within its constructor there is set of *binding* for **Content** dependency property.

### MyUserControlBase.cs

```
namespace BindingBeforeInitComp
{
    using System.Diagnostics;

    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

    public class MyUserControlBase : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyContent",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(MyUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, MyContentChangedCallback));

        public MyUserControlBase()
        {
            // Set binding to the Content property.
            var propertyPath = new PropertyPath("Content");
            var binding = new Binding { Path = propertyPath, Source = this };
            SetBinding(MyContentProperty, binding);
        }

        public object MyContent
        {
            get { return GetValue(MyContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyContentProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void MyContentChangedCallback(
            DependencyObject dependencyObject,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            Debugger.Break(); // Breaking here to show that binding to Content property has updated.
        }
    }
}
```

There is also **MyUserControl**(cs+xaml) derived from **MyUserControlBase**. In the constructor there is default IntializeComponents() method (Note: binding was set before this method in the base constructor). Before calling of IntializeComponents() the Content property is null, after calling Content is set to content described in xaml. But binding does not update a target property.

### MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```
namespace BindingBeforeInitComp
{
    using System.Diagnostics;

    using Windows.UI;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

    public sealed partial class MyUserControl : MyUserControlBase
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            Debugger.Break(); // Here Content is null.

            InitializeComponent();

            Debugger.Break(); // Here Content is set, but as you can see there is no binding update.
        }

        private void ChangeContentClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Change content by a click. In this case the property changing should trigger update.
            Content = new Grid() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Chartreuse) };
        }
    }
}
```

### MyUserControl.xaml

```
<local:MyUserControlBase
    x:Class="BindingBeforeInitComp.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BindingBeforeInitComp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Background="OrangeRed">
        <Button Click="ChangeContentClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="150" Background="#FF00AE4F">Change content</Button>
    </Grid>
</local:MyUserControlBase>
```

Full sources: https://github.com/inTagger/Bugs/tree/master/BindingBeforeInitComp

**UPDATE**: I have updated sources on the GitHub, added WPF (NET45) project to demonstrate the true way how dependency properties and bindings should work. And yes, WPF has no such problem (behavior/feature/bug).

**UPDATE2**: If Content dependency property is set directly in constructor - binding works, but not if Content is set somewhere inside InitializeComponents().

Answer (score 0):

The `InitializeComponent` method's job is to load your Xaml, so it's to be expected that none of your UI elements are available until after it has run.

Consider handling the `Loaded` event - you can attach a handler to that in your base constructor, and it won't be raised until after the object is fully constructed.

Comment: I'm not talking about UI elements (visual tree from the xaml). I'm talking about dependency properties which are updated while InitializeComponents() method is running. And bindings to these properties do not work until constructor ends.

Comment: the Loaded event is probably too late because I think inTagger wants to customize the content *before* the whole view is actually attached to the visual tree.

What I think is that inside the ctor, WinRT does not directly set the Content but sets it in some sort of private field. This way it has a slight performance improvement (no handling of events, etc), but it breaks the logic.

Comment: Unfortunately, you effectively are talking about UI elements. (I agree if WinRT was consistent, you wouldn't be, but unfortunately, that's not how it is.) The fact that WPF made `UserControl` derive from `ContentControl` was always a bit of a hack - it was a somewhat last minute thing as the first previews didn't have `UserControl`. In WinRT, they left this behind, and now `UserControl` gets special handling. An unfortunate upshot is that its `Content` property isn't normal.